# mongoos pulling array element base on objectId

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, pull

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjkfC.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64wwx.png)i have an mongoose schema that contain array if object the refer to an other schema how can i remove some of the array element by object id

```
const Event = mongoose.model(
    "Event",
    new mongoose.Schema({
        hostId: String,
        title: String,
        date: String,
        guestsId: [{
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User"
        }]

    })
);
```

i want to remove guestId element base on objectId

this is my controller

```
exports.deleteGuestById = (req, res) => {
    Event.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.id }, { $pull: { guestsId: { _id: req.body.guestsId } } }, { new: true }).populate("guestsId")
        .then((h) => {
            res.send(`${h} removed`)
        }).catch(e => { res.send(e) })
```

This is from bongodb

[image: 3]

im passing event id to url and guestId as body

Comment: The question post with proper formatting and text (avoid using links with your data and code) will allow viewers to read (and possibly reply) to your question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Feel free to edit your post - just a further suggestion.